# Associated tags in an Azure DevOps release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is there a way to retrieve the list of tags associated to a specific release while running (e.g. within a PowerShell task)?

I searched in the [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), but I could not find anything about it.

I could also get the information using the REST API, but I would like to avoid redundant work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For release pipeline, you can find related variables [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#artifact-variables).

I think you can use `Release.Artifacts.{alias}.SourceVersion` to get closest commit for your release. And then you can use some git command to get tags the commit has.

For me, I use something like this in `Command Line` task:

```
echo Get the tags.
git tag --points-at $(Release.Artifacts._GithubPermissionTest.SourceVersion
```

Result in log:

[image]

It do output the tags the commit has. And you can also do similar job in PS task.

[image]

Also, if you want to get tags from build instead of release, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56326940/how-to-get-git-tag-in-azure-pipelines). Hope it helps.